# Understanding Serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

**Context**

I'm trying to understand how to use Serialization, never used it previously.

**Right now I have a populate method in my singleton object (Main class) that basically adds a few member objects to a list of members using my addMember methods**

**I want to serialize this Members List** Once I can serialize and deserialize the list I can delete my populate method.

**Questions**

- HOW do I serialize this list so that the members list is deserialized upon startup?
- WHERE do I serialize specifically? Do I serialize when I'm creating a new member, or do I just serialize the list at shutdown and deserialize at startup.
- Since member information can be edited, how do I serialize the updates and overwrite the previously held data?

**Code Listings**

I'm kinda new to Serialization, but here's my code, I'm using a method for this because I I think it's cleaner this way, using ISerializable in my main class. Here's a few snippets from my main class, keep in mind I have tons of comments in my code, that's kinda why I didn't post this previously:

```
namespace HillRacingGraded
{
    [Serializable]
    public class HillRacing : ISerializable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Singleton object hillracing
        /// </summary>
        private static HillRacing hillracing;

        GUIUtility gui = new GUIUtility();


        /// <summary>
        /// Instance property returns the singleton instance
        /// </summary>
        public static HillRacing Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (hillracing == null)
                    hillracing = new HillRacing();
                return hillracing;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// public Property that returns races list, can be accessed by other classes.
        /// </summary>
        public List<BaseRace> Races
        {
            get
            {
                return races;
            }
            set
            {
                races = value;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// public Property that returns members list, can be accessed by other classes.
        /// </summary>
        public List<BaseMember> Members
        {
            get
            {
                return members;
            }
            set
            {
                members = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// instantiate the list of members
        /// </summary>
        private List<BaseMember> members; //I WANT TO SERIALIZE THIS

        /// <summary>
        /// instantiate the list of races
        /// </summary>
        private List<BaseRace> races; //I WANT TO SERIALIZE THIS

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor for hillracing.
        /// </summary>
        public HillRacing()
        {
            //members is a new list of the BaseMember objects.
            //races is a new list of the BaseRace objects.


            members = new List<BaseMember>();
            races = new List<BaseRace>();

            //call the populate method on launch, mostly for testing purposes.
            Populate();


        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Hillracing constructor for serialization
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info"></param>
        /// <param name="ctxt"></param>
        public HillRacing(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
        {
             this.members = (List<BaseMember>)info.GetValue("Members", typeof(List<BaseMember>));
             this.races = (List<BaseRace>)info.GetValue("Races", typeof(List<BaseRace>));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// get object data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info"></param>
        /// <param name="ctxt"></param>
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
         {
             info.AddValue("Members", this.members);
         }


        /// <summary>
        ///  Adds a new junior member to the list of all members.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stringfirstname">first name of the member</param>
        /// <param name="stringlastname">last name of the member</param>
        /// <param name="stringmiddlename">middle name of the member</param>
        /// <param name="stringtitle">title of the member</param>
        /// <param name="strst">street of the member</param>
        /// <param name="strtwn">Town of the member</param>
        /// <param name="strpc">Postcode of the member</param>
        /// <param name="strEmail">email of the member</param>
        /// <param name="intMobile">Mobile of the member</param>
        /// <param name="intHome">Home phone of the member</param>
        /// <param name="shrnumber">ID number of the member</param>
        /// <param name="memtype">Type of the member</param>
        /// <param name="username">username of the member</param>
        /// <param name="noracesrun">number of races that the member has run</param>
        /// <param name="perraceswon">percentage of races that the member has won</param>
        /// <param name="mempic">image of the member</param>
        /// <param name="memclub">the club the member is part of</param>
        /// <param name="gender">the gender of the member</param>
        /// <param name="memexp">the experience level the member has</param>
        /// <param name="yearofbirth">the year of birth the member was born in</param>
        /// <param name="monthofbirth">the month of birth the member was born in</param>
        /// <param name="dayofbirth">the day of birth the member was born on</param>
        public void addJunior(string stringfirstname, string stringlastname, string stringmiddlename, string stringtitle, string strst, string strtwn, string strpc, string strEmail, int intMobile, int intHome,
            string shrnumber, string memtype, string username, string password, int noracesrun, float perraceswon, string mempic, string memclub, string gender, int memexp, int yearofbirth, int monthofbirth, int dayofbirth, string nextofkin, string docName, string docTel, string healthIssues, string parentalConsent)
        {

            // create a new member with the entered parameters to add to the list.
            JuniorMember newMember = new JuniorMember(stringfirstname, stringlastname, stringmiddlename, stringtitle, strst, strtwn, strpc, strEmail, intMobile, intHome, shrnumber, memtype, username, password, noracesrun, perraceswon, mempic, memclub, gender, memexp, yearofbirth, monthofbirth, dayofbirth,nextofkin,docName,docTel,healthIssues,parentalConsent);

            //use add functionality of list to add to the list.
            members.Add(newMember);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stringfirstname">first name of the member</param>
        /// <param name="stringlastname">last name of the member</param>
        /// <param name="stringmiddlename">middle name of the member</param>
        /// <param name="stringtitle">title of the member</param>
        /// <param name="strst">street of the member</param>
        /// <param name="strtwn">Town of the member</param>
        /// <param name="strpc">Postcode of the member</param>
        /// <param name="strEmail">email of the member</param>
        /// <param name="intMobile">Mobile of the member</param>
        /// <param name="intHome">Home phone of the member</param>
        /// <param name="shrnumber">ID number of the member</param>
        /// <param name="memtype">Type of the member</param>
        /// <param name="username">username of the member</param>
        /// <param name="noracesrun">number of races that the member has run</param>
        /// <param name="perraceswon">percentage of races that the member has won</param>
        /// <param name="mempic">image of the member</param>
        /// <param name="memclub">the club the member is part of</param>
        /// <param name="gender">the gender of the member</param>
        /// <param name="memexp">the experience level the member has</param>
        /// <param name="yearofbirth">the year of birth the member was born in</param>
        /// <param name="monthofbirth">the month of birth the member was born in</param>
        /// <param name="dayofbirth">the day of birth the member was born on</param>
        /// <param name="nextofkin">The next family member contact</param>
        /// <param name="docName">The name of the members doctor</param>
        /// <param name="docTel">A telephone number for the doctor</param>
        /// <param name="healthIssues">the health issues this member has.</param>
        public void addSenior(string stringfirstname, string stringlastname, string stringmiddlename, string stringtitle, string strst, string strtwn, string strpc, string strEmail, int intMobile, int intHome,
            string shrnumber, string memtype, string username, string password, int noracesrun, float perraceswon, string mempic, string memclub, string gender, int memexp, int yearofbirth, int monthofbirth, int dayofbirth, string nextofkin, string docName, string docTel, string healthIssues)
        {

            //create a new member with the entered parameters to add to the list.
            SeniorMember newMember = new SeniorMember(stringfirstname, stringlastname, stringmiddlename, stringtitle, strst, strtwn, strpc, strEmail, intMobile, intHome, shrnumber, memtype, username, password, noracesrun, perraceswon, mempic, memclub, gender, memexp, yearofbirth, monthofbirth, dayofbirth,docName,docTel,healthIssues);

            //use standard list functionality of list to add this new member to the list.
            members.Add(newMember);

        }
```

Here is my Serialization method in the Serializer class:

```
    public void SerializeObject(string filename, object objectToSerialize)
    {
        Stream stream = File.Open(filename + ".bin", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        bFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
        stream.Close();
    }
```

Problem is, I don't know how to actually use this.

Also have a deserializer:

```
public HillRacing DeSerializeObject(string filename)
{
    HillRacing hillracing;
    Stream stream = File.Open(filename + ".bin", FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    hillracing = (HillRacing)bFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
    return hillracing;
}
```

Comment: "I'm kinda new to Serialization." - so presumably a search for some sort of introductory tutorial might be useful....

Comment: They're very convoluted, I'm looking for a simple explanatory response.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms233843.aspx

Comment: so, you're saying that every tutorial out there is not understandable?

Comment: Well, I made a Serializer class and I tried to get it working with my code, I'm using Iserializable in my main class and have both serialize and deserialize methods, but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) has some great easy to follow examples.  Note that there are a number of ways to serialize and you havent indicated which method you are after

Comment: _"I made a Serializer class and I tried to get it working with my code"_ -- and presumably it doesn't work? Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows clearly what you've tried, along with a clear, precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. As stated, your question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. Help others help you by presenting the _specific_ detail you need help on with respect to getting the code to work.

Comment: Well thanks a bunch guys, I was just asking for a little bit of help understanding serialization. There's no need to be rude.

The code I have is generic therein lies the reason why I didn't post it, it's standard serialization. my main issue is I don't know what I'm meant to be passing into my methods, the object presumably, but at which stage? creation of a member or the entire members list?

These were the questions I was asking, I'll ask elsewhere.

Most examples use serialization directly from classes, but I can't do this because my classes already inherit from other classes.

Comment: what is "standard serialization"?  BinaryFormatter?  JSON? ProtoBuf? Gobs of questions here on serialization if you dont like MSDN

Comment: Standard, as in, whenever someone googles "Serialization in C#" you'll get example code somewhere along the lines of this. Like I said, I'm new to serialization, this is the first time I'm attempting to use it.

Comment: @Method - No-one is being rude to you here. They are all trying to help you. You need to understand that we can't help you properly unless you can provide us with a clear mental dump of your question. Simply saying "standard serialization" isn't enough as there are so many ways to perform serialization in .Net that I wouldn't call any of them standard. Please help us to help you by responding to our questions in a positive can-do manner.

Comment: I provided the code requested. I just don't know how to serialize a specific list in my main class using the methods I showed, that link is currently non-existent. and that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have done most of the part i suggest a little generics make it multiuse as

```
public static class StreamUtilities
{
    public static T GetObject<T>(Byte[] rawimage) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();

            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            memStream.Write(rawimage, 0, rawimage.Length);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return binForm.Deserialize(memStream) as T;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public static  Byte[] Serialize<T>(this T obj) where T:class
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

then in your main class or whereever you want it to use include to namespace where the above extention method is then use

```
Object1 a=new Object1();// any serializable object
serializedbytes=a.Serialize<Object1>();
//deserialize
Object b=StreamUtilities.GetObject<Object1>(serializedbytes);
```

The above extention method will allow to seriailize/Deserialize any serializable Object.